# Here Public Transport Routing Maximum Distance to Station not working

Tags: javascript, routes, here-api

I am trying to query some public transport data from the here API.
However, I am struggeling with when the origin point is far away from a station. In the API reference there is the `pedestrian[distance]` paramter. I, however, simply cant make it work.

[image]

This query for example:

```
https://transit.router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apiKey=<API_KEY>origin=48.3787,16.5122&destination=48.211029313540855,16.347822689187193&modes=cityTrain&departureTime=2021-10-26T08:08:00&pedestrian[100000]
```

Return this:

[image]

Is there any way I can alway make sure to get a result. Even when the next station is e.g. 20 km far away?

Comment: Can you try `pedestrian[maxDistance]=100000` instead?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your URL is not correctly formed, please try to use this one instead: [https://transit.router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apiKey={APIKEY}&origin=48.3787,16.5122&destination=48.211029313540855,16.347822689187193&modes=cityTrain&departureTime=2021-10-26T08:08:00&pedestrian[maxDistance]=6000](https://transit.router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apiKey=%7BAPIKEY%7D&origin=48.3787,16.5122&destination=48.211029313540855,16.347822689187193&modes=cityTrain&departureTime=2021-10-26T08:08:00&pedestrian%5BmaxDistance%5D=6000)

Comment: thank you very much!:) You know what is the max distance value I can provide? And is there any nice workaround if there is no station near?

Comment: The maximum walking distance will be 6km, if there is no stations within 6km then there won't be a valid route.